# How can I sum a result in sql when the other results of other column are the same?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi and sorry if I don't do the question the correct way

I have this query :

```
SELECT
t4.tar_nombre as nombre_tarea,
t2.rdi_fechacti as fecha_actividad,
t3.rea_hrstarea as horas_trabajadas

FROM
    act_usuario t1
INNER JOIN
    act_regisdiario t2
ON
    (t2.usu_id = t1.usu_id)
INNER JOIN
    act_registtarea t3
ON
    (t3.rdi_id = t2.rdi_id)
INNER JOIN
    act_tarea t4
ON
    (t4.tar_id = t3.tar_id)
WHERE
    t4.usu_id = 4 
GROUP BY

    t3.rea_id

ORDER BY
    t2.rdi_fechacti
```

And the query print this :

[image]

So, I need when in "fecha_Actividad" exist the same "nombre_actividad" , thats only show me one "fecha_actividad" and the sum of "horas_trabajadas".

For example the query show this:

[image]

But I need this (because the same "nombre_tarea" is in the same date):

[image]

The reference:

[image]

Sorry my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `SUM(field)` syntax after grouping.

```
SELECT
    t4.tar_nombre as nombre_tarea,
    t2.rdi_fechacti as fecha_actividad,
    t3.rea_hrstarea as horas_trabajadas,
    SUM(t3.rea_hrstarea)
FROM
    act_usuario t1
INNER JOIN
    act_regisdiario t2
ON
    (t2.usu_id = t1.usu_id)
INNER JOIN
    act_registtarea t3
ON
(t3.rdi_id = t2.rdi_id)
INNER JOIN
    act_tarea t4
ON
    (t4.tar_id = t3.tar_id)
WHERE
    t4.usu_id = 4 
GROUP BY
    t4.tar_nombre
ORDER BY
    t2.rdi_fechacti
```

There are also other functions you can use on grouped results. You can find them [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: Hi , and thx , but that query show me the same of column that "horas_trabajadas" , i need for example in "nombre_tarea" is  "prueba de tarea" twice and I need see "prueba de tarea" only one. and sum 5 + 3 = 8 because  "nombre_tarea" is twice  in "fecha_actividad"

Comment: @Jeanbf remove `t3.rea_id` from `GROUP BY` and it'll sum that.